# How to configure Doxygen/chmcmd to come up with closed sections?

Tags: doxygen, chm

I make my docs using Doxygen/chmcmd in .chm form. I have many sections, subsections, etc. and I would prefer CHM to come up in the 'Contents' tab of the navigation pane with all but the top (@page) items closed.

Is there any option I can set for that?

**Edit:** Added HTML config file

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = @CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@/../doc
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            =
HTML_FOOTER            =
HTML_STYLESHEET        =
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  =
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = YES
CHM_FILE               = @CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME@.chm
HHC_LOCATION           =
```

Comment: How is your current configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to open topics individually in a workflow like **Doxygen/chmcmd** you described. It is up to the user to open or close the topics individually. There is no formal way to achieve this.

But, what most help authoring folk - with special knowledge using HH Workshop - end up doing is moving the CHM home page (e.g. `DefaultTopic=Index.htm` - Default topic to open when CHM is opened.) deeper into the TOC. That way if AutoSync is enabled the TOC will automatically expand to show the HomePage and its peer nodes when help opens.

You may know a broad pallet is offered at the CHM files about mouse buttons and keyboard to functions to the navigation in the different windows. The user can individually decide in favor of this way after his personal habits e.g. right-click in the table of contents, and then click Open All.

[image]

This opens all books or folders in the table of contents. This command only works if the Contents tab is displayed.

[image]

For further information see also: [Accessibility shortcut keys Help Viewer](https://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_shortcuts.htm)